# Eloquent method to analyse a four dimensional system ODEs qualitatively

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, mathematical-modeling

Given a nonlinear four dimensional system of ODEs, I have found the fixed point and linearized to acquire the Jacobian. I am beginning to calculate the eigenvalues of the Jacobian from the quartic characteristic polynomial.

The Jacobian's elements consist of functions that are not specified, for example $F(x,y)$ and $F_x(x,y)$. Also, $C_\infty$ differentiability is assumed. I do not want to use numerical analysis.

References would be useful--typically textbooks analyse two dimensional systems qualitatively, but do not go higher, which suggests to me I am taking an unconventional approach.

Should I be using a symbolic manipulation computer package?

Comment: First you should compute the stationary points. Without that, the linearization is not very meaningful.

Comment: Thanks. Yes i have computed the stationary points.

Comment: Then can you please reformulate the second paragraph? It is not quite clear. The Jacobian in the stationary points is a numerical matrix. Or in general, the Jacobian consists of the partial derivatives of the functions. What is "their derivatives" and what does "functional form" refer to? -- One might be interested in lower degree Taylor polynomials. But rarely in the full "functional form" of the eigenvalues or other expressions, the intermediate and final expressions, starting from the Jacobian and the system for stationarity, might become quite vast.

Comment: I updated the question. I am reviewing your suggestion. Specifically, whether the stationary point pins down the elements of the Jacobian, which I now understand it may.